# Как сравнить ответ requests.get()

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Нужно отловить ответ `requests.get()`, если он не равен 200 и записать в БД.

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.tesli.com/product/')
print(response)
if response == '<Response [200]>':
    print('NO')
```

Этот скрипт просто для примера.
Как сравнить response с возможной ошибкой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
if response.status_code == 200:
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот так вот:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.tesli.com/product/')
print(response)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('NO')
```